# Redirect a user from my website to mobile app

Tags: redirect, expo, vercel

I have this middleware function running on vercel that I'm attempting to redirect users with. The link is generated on Expo and it contains a deeplink to my app. This link gets emailed to the user for auth purposes.

The link looks like this

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect?redirectUrl=exp://192.168.1.0:9000&mode=signIn&lang=en&apiKey=xxxx&oobCode=xxxx
```

So I manage to get the expo link I want to direct too but it never goes to my app because

> https://www.mywebsite.com

always gets added to the link so I end up with

> https://www.mywebsite.com/exp://192.168.1.0:9000&mode=signIn&lang=en&apiKey=xxxx&oobCode=xxxx

How can I modify my function to direct to the Expo link?

---

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function redirects(req, res) {
  const { url } = req;
  const { href, origin, searchParams } = req.nextUrl;

  if (href.includes("redirectUrl")) {
    let extractedUrl = url.split("?")[1];
    let redirectUrl = extractedUrl.replace("redirectUrl=", "");

    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Went a different route with this. Did the redirect without the middleware and regular getInitialProps if anyone was interested.

This is what I came up with. Feel free to suggest how I can improve this.

```
Redirects.getInitialProps = (ctx) => {
  if (!ctx.res) return;
  const { redirectUrl, mode, lang, apiKey, oobCode } = ctx.query;
  const Location = `${redirectUrl}${mode}${lang}${apiKey}${oobCode}`;

  if (redirectUrl) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location });
    ctx.res.end(`Redirecting to ${Location}`);
  } else {
    ctx.res.writeHead(400);
    ctx.res.end("You must provide a `redirectUrl` in the query");
  }
};
```